# How can I get GPS data even on background on Android?

Tags: java, android, gps

I have an application that uses both GPS and Network location providers. When I turn on the GPS , I'm recording the locatin data to an arraylist. Then I'm drawing my GPS track with a button. But the problem is when program goes background I can't get any  location data. So the lines being drawed dashed.

I'm removing both of the providers under  **onStop()** function. But when I removed that order its just stopping again.

How can I get data even on background  ?

Comment: Service ? Can you explain what do you mean ? I'm trying to learn. Do you mean wakelocks ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: @zgc7009 thank you :)
A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.

Comment: what about passing the computation to a Async task with a timer?

Comment: When I was started to learn about location aware programs I wrote very simple one (Only showing latitude and longitude on the screen) and I was realized that this program never stops getting information from location service. Then I've learned that I should remove listeners to avoid this because in that case battery was flowing. The confusing part for me is ; I want to do this on my program under the control of user. Normally I want to use location service just to show my location. But when I click GPS track button I want program keep running on background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a full working sample using the Google Play Services fused location (which is what you should be using).

https://github.com/nickfox/GpsTracker/tree/master/phoneClients/android

that is built with Android Studio. And I also have a tutorial that explains how it works here:

https://www.websmithing.com/2014/04/23/how-the-gpstracker-android-client-works/

And finally, to learn more about the new Android location services, read this:

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html